# What does こと mean in this context? こと脚に関しては他のサーヴァントより優位におるぞ

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 余はライダー。**こと**脚に関しては他のサーヴァントより優位におるぞ。

https://soundcloud.com/felipem-ller/wed-feb-13-2019-1

So, sorry for repeating the title, but the question is simple, what does こと mean in this context?

Comment: Doesn't the speaker say「こと**は**あしにかんしては」?

Comment: Honestly I do also hear a は there, so I don't know what to make of this, at the moment both answers make sense to me.

Comment: If people claim they hear something, they hear it, so I won't argue that.  Truth is, however, 「こと**は**脚に関しては」 makes little to no sense. We already have a good answer as I type this.

Comment: No need to apologize for including the full context in the title -- this makes it **much** clearer what the question is.  Post titles like "what does X mean" are entirely too vague.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi iirc I added the context to the title.

Comment: Cheers then @EddieKal, thank you for doing so!  

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<del>こと in expressions  「**こと**～～となると」「**こと**～～に関しては」「**こと**ここに至っては」 etc. means "things", 事, 事態.</del>

<del>「こと～～となると」「こと～～に関しては」 mean "When it comes to~".

cf. 「ことここに至っては」 = "now that things have come to this"</del>

---

**EDIT:**
On second thought, it's more reasonable to think of it as [殊]{こと}, "especially", "among other things", ≂「[殊]{こと}に」 「特に」「とりわけ」.

「こと～～に関しては、...」「こと～～となると、...」「こと～～については、...」 are expressions to say "Regarding ~~, among other things, ..." "Especially when it comes to~~, ..."

This usage of こと is quite literary (and maybe a little archaic?). I don't think I've seen this こと used in other expressions.

Comment: 何を言おうとしているだろうと考えると何とかそうであってほしいと感じる…でも、「殊」＋「は」って？

Comment: 「ことXXに関しては」「ことXXとなると」「ことXXについては」って形で、決まった言い方なので・・

Comment: OPで書いてある文章ならば分かりますが、音声はお聞きになりましたか？「ことは」に聞こえませんか？

Comment: はい、聞きましたよ、大御所の大塚明夫さんの声ですね！ええ声～　「こと」と「あし」の間、ちょっと伸ばしてる感じですね。 ["こと * に関しては他のサーヴァントより"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=JB1mXOiAMY6g-QbrnKvQCw&q="こと+*+に関しては他のサーヴァントより") でググれは、セリフがわかりますよ。いずれも、「こと足に関しては」か「こと脚に関しては」で、「ことは～」となっているページはありませんね。

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my own question again now from 3 years ago haha

Listening to this again, It sounds like just a contraction for "ってことは" which means something like "so that means that"