# Understanding こと in this context: 『...こと戦技教練の成績は飛び抜けて良かった』

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> 所詮間に合わせの数合わせに過ぎない特士校で、口減らし**に入れられた**子供ばかりの候補生の中ではそれなりに優秀、**こと**戦技教練の成績は飛び抜けて良かった。けれど命令違反等の問題行動もやたら多くて、結局どこぞの試験部隊に転属になった。戦闘属領出身の最下層の人獣どもばかりの、特攻兵器を扱わされる懲罰部隊だという噂の。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

How should I understand the usage of the bold こと? What is this grammar phenomenon? By the way, can I understand the に入れられた as "counted as"? If not, does the に mean ために?

Comment: 殊: [What does こと mean in this context? こと脚に関しては他のサーヴァントより優位におるぞ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65483/43676)

Comment: 入れられた literally means "put (into the school)."

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you. Then how should I understand the に in に入れられた?

Comment: That's for ために.

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you again. So the に indicates purpose (in order to), right?

Comment: Yes, 口 in this context means a mouth to feed in a household.